# How to use apply function instead of nested for loop?

Tags: r, excel, apply

I currently have a large matrix (3000x20) and want to compute an value using the values in first row and first column and a vector. My dataset (in excel) is like this (I use VBA code to create this excel):

```
SumRow = 0
SumCol = 0
RowInterval = 0.001
ColInterval = 0.01
For i = 2 To 3001
        Cells(i, 1).Value = SumRow + RowInterval
        SumPD = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next i
    For j = 2 To 21
        Cells(1, j).Value = SumCol + ColInterval
        SumRho = Cells(1, j).Value
    Next j
```

I am currently using the following R code to do the calculation

```
InputVector <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) 
Testing<-read.csv("InputFile.csv", header=FALSE)
    for (m in (2:(3001)))
    { for (n in (2:21))
        { Sum = 0
          Row = Testing(m,1)
          Col = Testing(1,n)
          for (p in (1:length(InputVector)))
                  { Sum = Sum + sqrt((1-Col)/Col)*exp(Row) }
                Testing[m,n] = Sum }  }
write.csv(Testing, "TestingOutput.csv")
```

Basically it first puts a vector (x values) into a formula f(x) and I want to print the sum of f(x) on excel with different parameters listed in the first row and first column in the excel.
I run the above code and it works, but it takes very long time. I am new to Apply Function and may I know how I can use the apply function to speed up the calculation and do the same output as above?

Comment: `apply` won't speed anything unless you will write a more efficient procedure (as this is the same `for` loop you already using). If you want help, I'd suggest you''ll provide some piece of the  `InputFile.csv` data set and show your desired output.

Comment: I think there is an error in your VBA code. You want `SumRow = Cells(i, 1).Value` and `SumCol = Cells(1, j).Value`.

Comment: What you have is nowhere close to legal R code.

Comment: @fgnu how do you define *legal R code* exactly?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Will it _run_?

Comment: @fgnu OP says it is. I also don't see anything illegal here. Can you spot something specific?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Well, here's one -- have you noticed that `Testing` is a `data.frame`?

Comment: @fgnu Oh I see it now, good catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a three line R solution to your problem, including generating the data:

```
library(reshape2)

# generate the combinations to iterate over
vInput = seq(1, 10)
dfSeq = expand.grid(rowSeq = seq(from = 0, by = 0.001, length.out = 3000),
            colSeq = seq(from = 0, by = 0.01, length.out = 20))

# generate the values
dfSeq = cbind.data.frame(result = mapply(function(row, col) {
  length(vInput)*sqrt((1-col)/col)*exp(row)
}, dfSeq$rowSeq, dfSeq$colSeq), dfSeq)

# cast them in the shape required
dfSeqWide = dcast(dfSeq, rowSeq~colSeq, value.var = "result")
```